# How to add an HTML element starting after one and finishing before another one

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can't find a solution to my problem, hope you can help :

I got this :

```html
<hr id="first-hr" /> 
<p> lorem ipsum </p>
<span> bla bla bla </span>
<hr />
```

I'd like to, automatically in javascript, add a parent to anything beetween an identified hr and the next one

```html
<hr id="first-hr" /> 
<div id="my-new-div">
        <p> lorem ipsum </p>
        <span> bla bla bla </span>
</div>
<hr />
```

The goal is to add some style to this div by adding a class. If it is simpler to retrieve all elements between the identified hr and the next one and add a class to them without adding a parent, I'm fine with that too!

Thanks ! <3

Comment: what style do you want to apply to the parent div?

Comment: add some background color

Comment: would it work for you to add the background color on <p> and <span> elements?

Comment: Wouldn't this be a simple matter of looping through the hr identifiers, save their innerHTML into a variable and replacing it with `'<div id="my-new-div">' + oldHtml + '</div>'`? Should note here that you shouldn't do that with an `id` as those are supposed to be unique. But the idea is the same. Just use a class instead of an id for the CSS

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan as I said, yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will loop over all the siblings of the `first-hr` element, appending them to a `div` which is inserted after the `first-hr` element:

```js
const hr = document.getElementById('first-hr')
let next = hr.nextSibling
const div = document.createElement('div')
hr.parentNode.insertBefore(div, next)
div.setAttribute('id', 'my-new-div')
while (next) {
  let node = next
  next = next.nextSibling
  div.appendChild(node)
  if (!next || next.nodeName == 'HR') break
}
```

```css
#my-new-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<hr id="first-hr">
<p id="x"> lorem ipsum </p>
<span> bla bla bla </span>
<hr />
```

Here's another way to do it which doesn't have any explicit looping in it, but of course it is present, hidden inside calls to `indexOf` and `findIndex`:

```js
const hr = document.getElementById('first-hr')
let siblings = [...hr.parentNode.childNodes]
siblings = siblings.slice(siblings.indexOf(hr)+1)
const nexthr = siblings.findIndex(n => n.nodeName == 'HR')
siblings = siblings.slice(0, nexthr)
const div = document.createElement('div')
div.setAttribute('id', 'my-new-div')
div.append(...siblings)
hr.parentNode.insertBefore(div, hr.nextSibling)
```

```css
#my-new-div {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<hr id="first-hr">
<p id="x"> lorem ipsum </p>
<span> bla bla bla </span>
<hr />
```

Comment: indeed, working ! would have loved a solution without looping but maybe it's not possible ! thanks anyway.

Comment: @arnaudbey because the elements are siblings, not children, I think you *have* to iterate. If they were children you could just move them all at once.

Comment: @arnaudbey btw I made a slight edit to the code to make it more robust in the case where there's no finishing `<hr>` element

Comment: @arnaudbey I've added an alternate solution which has no *explicit* looping in it...

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do what you described:

```js
function surround(id) {

  const hr = document.querySelector(id);
  const children = hr.parentNode.children;
  const include = [];
  let startIncluding = false;
  for (let child of children) {

    if (!startIncluding) {
      if (child === hr) startIncluding = true;
    } else {
      if (child.tagName !== 'HR') {
        include.push(child);
      } else {
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  const div = document.createElement('div');
  for (let child of include) {
    div.append(child);
  }
  div.className = 'new-div';
  hr.after(div);
}
```

```css
.new-div {
  background-color: #def;
  border: 2px dashed red;
  padding: 0 2em 1em 2em;
  border-radius: 3em;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="surround('#first-hr')">Surround First</button>
<button onclick="surround('#second-hr')">Surround Second</button>

<div class="wrapper">
  <hr id="first-hr" />
  <p> first: lorem ipsum </p>
  <span> first: bla bla bla </span>
  <hr />


  <hr id="second-hr" />
  <p> second: lorem ipsum </p>
  <span> second: bla bla bla </span>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to add class in a div tag insert this one inside `class="text-container"` it should look like `<div id="my-new-div class="text-container"">`.. once you are done try adding the class to css

```css
.text-container{
  
 background-color: aqua;
 margin
}
```

```html
<hr id="first-hr" /> 
<div class="text-container" id="my-new-div" >
        <p> lorem ipsum </p>
        <span> bla bla bla </span>
</div>
<hr />
```

if you want to style `h1` add class and style it to css

Comment: # is also applicable and this style will only apply to the element with that particular id

Comment: How does this solve OPs question?

Comment: i'd like this to be automatic, with javascript :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).